# Optional Parameters in Delphi

Tags: object, delphi, pascal

My question is: How to skip an optional parameter when we want to pass the value of the next optional parameter?

Code example. Having the following procedure:

```
procedure MetodoDeEjemplo(requerido: integer; cadenaOpcional: string = 'cadena por defecto'; enteroOpcional: integer = 1);
```

I want to pass the value of the parameter: requerido and enteroOpcional

```
MetodoDeEjemplo(3, ,9);
```

Without passing the cadenaOpcional value.

How is it done in Delphi to skip an optional parameter, without a compilation error?

Comment: You cannot do that. However, you can have several [overloaded](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Procedures_and_Functions_(Delphi)#Overloading_Procedures_and_Functions) procedures, in this case `Integer`, `Integer, string`, `Integer, Integer`, and `Integer, string, Integer`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand In C # I know that this is solved by naming the parameter example: `MetodoDeEjemplo(3, enteroOpcional: 4); ` in delphi this possibility does not exist?

Comment: @jmontegrosso No, that's not possible.

Comment: In most Pascal dialects you can't define optional parameters at all.

Comment: (afaik strictly speaking it is possible, but only for calls to dispatch interfaces, but that doesn't help with this example)

Comment: You could do that if you change the order of the parameters in your procedure. You see omitting optional parameters only work when you omit one or more rightmost parameters. For instance if you have a procedure with five parameters where last four are optional you can can for instance pass first two and then omit the rest. But you can't pass first, omit second, pass then third and omit rest.